# Google Translate changes the alignment of the html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-translate

When I change the language in google translate the alignment of the divs changes.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: always add as much as information you can, this will help while giving answers to your question. Plz add some sample code etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.